# Haxe JS Http.requestUrl fails with InvalidAccessError

Tags: haxe

In haxe/js, synchronous http requests fail. For example, this

```
haxe.Http.requestUrl("http://www.anyurl.com");
```

results in this error on Firefox:

```
InvalidAccessError: XMLHttpRequest.responseType setter: synchronous XMLHttpRequests do not support timeout and responseType
```

It looks like the haxe/js http implementation sets responseType [here](https://github.com/HaxeFoundation/haxe/blob/development/std/haxe/http/HttpJs.hx#L121).

Is there a workaround?

Answer (score 3):

https://api.haxe.org/haxe/http/HttpBase.html

> This class can be used to handle Http requests consistently across
> platforms. There are two intended usages:
>
> - call haxe.Http.requestUrl(url) and receive the result as a String (only available on sys targets)
> - create a new haxe.Http(url), register your callbacks for onData, onError and onStatus, then call request().

Example: https://try.haxe.org/#1E28AD28

Comment: The first option (my example) doesn't work in JS. The second option (your example) makes an async call. I was asking about synchronous. So it sounds like synchronous http calls are not supported. But then I don't understand why [Httpjs.requestUrl](https://api.haxe.org/haxe/http/HttpJs.html#requestUrl) exists.

Comment: The example you gave can be made synchronous by adding `http.async = false;`, but then it'll give the same error.

Comment: First option _only available on **sys** targets_

Comment: I saw that, but the existence of a js-specific synch http call implementation in the std lib seemed like an apparent contradiction. I guess that method is just meant for old browsers or node or something else. It sounds like there's no workaround. Http calls must be async.

Comment: Yes, looks they should be async due browsers behaviour
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Synchronous_and_Asynchronous_Requests#synchronous_request

`Note: Starting with Gecko 30.0 (Firefox 30.0 / Thunderbird 30.0 / SeaMonkey 2.27), Blink 39.0, and Edge 13, synchronous requests on the main thread have been deprecated due to their negative impact on the user experience.`

Why you need sync calls?

Comment: I don't _need_ sync calls. I was trying to revive old code that used to work and ran into this. The Httpjs class seemed to support sync calls (it had the `requestUrl` method and the `async` attribute) so I thought I was missing something. It must be working for everybody else, otherwise it wouldn't be there, right? So I asked the question to find out how to properly use it.

Answer (score 1):

You may add a copy of HttpJs in your project and tweak it as you need to, but - as people have already pointed out - synchronous requests freeze the entire web page for the duration and have been deprecated for *years* due to this.